# Type-based declaration in quasar with vue3 js

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar

I have trouble using [vue 3 type-based props declaration](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props:%7E:text=This%20is%20called%20%22type%2Dbased%20declaration%22) with quasar framework (version 2.7.5, vue version 3.2.37).
When I define props in a component this way :

```
<template>
  <h1>
    HELLO {{props.name}}
  </h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  'name': string
}
const props = defineProps<Props>();
</script>
```

Called in parent component : `<hello-world name="John" />`

My problem: `props.name` evaluation remains empty.

But when I define props using runtime declaration style (ie. props declaration becomes `const props = defineProps({'name': String});`), then `props.name` is well evaluated to `John`.

=> I've probably missed a conf in `quasar.config.js` (I use the default one, generated with a simple yarn create quasar, all default choices except script type (typescript) and Quasar App CLI with Vite - this is a spa) ? Do you have any idea what is wrong ?